# X server error due to possible hardware issue?

Tags: hardware, x-server

I am running Linux Mint 17, and have encountered an X server error that prevented the OS from booting, similar to the error described [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=105156).

Typically, such an error suggests a problem with the drivers or OS.

However, the fact that the error goes away automatically after a few hours points towards a hardware issue. This has happened a few times over the past couple of years.

Can a malfunction of the motherboard or graphics card result in the X server error?

Comment: That linked forum post is severely outdated - are you sure you have the same issue? Could you be more specific on the error? Your question is ambiguous and I can only answer to the last sentence: yes, a HW malfunction certainly can and usually does result in X error, especially if the malfunction is graphics-related.